# JavaScript alert will not display after initializing "require" variable

Tags: javascript, require

I'm just getting started with JavaScript and have not seen a thread with my specific issue. A simple HTML file wants to execute a JavaScript file

```
<html>
    <head>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="/home/gewurztraminer/workspace/morpheme/site/index.js"></script>
    <body>
        <p>test</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

and in the JavaScript file I have a simple function invoked after a variable called net is equal to the requiring of 'net' string for server-related purposes.

```
var net = require('net');

(function() {

  alert("hi");

})();
```

The alert does not display in this case. But if I were to remove the first line so that only the function exists,

```
(function() {

  alert("hi");

})();
```

everything works fine. Can someone give a detailed explanation so that this is easily accessible to other newbies? The answer to this question is not readily available online.

Comment: Any error in console ?

Comment: I am not able to review the content of the console using console.log because I am using Sublime Text to run the code in localhost.

Comment: I assume the console (in your browser) shows the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined". I'm not sure what you expect "require" to be or do here. Are you missing some other script that defines it?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, require isn't a built-in method that allows you to use premade methods of the string type you enter in it? I see it used all the time.

Comment: *"It's good to keep off-topic threads alive in the event newbies run into similar issues). Go ahead edit this out to purify your site from unrelated suggestion."* - If it's off topic then it's off topic. Whinging about it in advance isn't going to put everybody on your side. Regarding use of `console.log()`, if you are viewing a web page in your browser then any `console.log()` statements log in the browser's console, which is accessible via the browser's dev tools (F12 in Chrome, IE, and FF).

Answer (score 3):

`require` is not a function provided by [the JavaScript language](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/) or by browsers.

It is a function provided by [Node.JS](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) (which doesn't run inside a browser) and various module loading scripts (such as [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/)).

Given that you are trying to load [a module called `net`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html), it looks like you are trying to run code designed to run under Node.JS in an HTML document in a web browser … which won't work.

Comment: I guess the more appropriate question then is how do I then build HTML code to run a JavaScript file as Node.js in Sublime Text?

Comment: You don't. JavaScript running in an HTML document and JavaScript running in Node.JS are significantly different beasts. If you want to run in an HTML document, then write JS that uses the APIs provided by browsers. If you want to use Node.JS modules, then don't involve an HTML document and run the JS with Node.JS.

Comment: Thank you! Further research will be done and I will post the answer when I have a comprehensive understanding of my error, that is, if I make it in time before the thread gets closed.

Comment: Unless you use tools like webpack or browserify